# Problema de modelagem de banco de dados

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, modelagem, modelo-relacional

Criei um sistema que no qual tem controle de vendas (`id`, `id_vendedor`, `produto`), vendedor (`id`, `nome`, `id_equipe`) e equipe (`id`, `nome`) numa empresa.

Exemplo: "João tem id: 1 e pertence à equipe: Azul; em Janeiro e nos primeiros 15 dias do mês ele vendeu 30 produtos; logo depois a empresa mudou ele para a equipe Vermelha e vendeu 25 produtos nos dias restantes do mês. Nesta empresa existe no total de 20 vendedores.".

Para fazer uma tabela de relatório com o Nome do vendedor, os produtos e equipes as quais pertence é fácil de fazer, mas gostaria de fazer um relatório que no qual ele mostre o nome de João e mostre a quantia de produtos vendidos por equipe e no final mostre a quantidade final somada nas duas equipes e o valor.

A dificuldade é o seguinte como o João tem só um `id` (e esse é único para cada vendedor) e eu só  posso editar a equipe. Como posso salvar no sistema  o id, nome e equipe a qual o vendedor está participando atualmente?

Answer (score 5):

O problema do seu modelo de dados é que não há histórico de equipes na qual um vendedor fez parte. Ou seja, se o vendedor fez parte de 10 times ao longo do histórico dele, as vendas serão contabilizadas levando-se em conta apenas o time atual.

Resumindo, seu modelo atual é esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O ideal seria que, na venda, fosse informado o produto, o vendedor e, opcionalmente, o time pelo qual aquela venda foi feita. Assim, é possível até que um produto tenha sido vendido por um vendedor sem que ele tenha necessariamente feito parte de um time.

O modelo, então, ficaria assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vale notar que nessa modelagem eu busquei resolver apenas seu problema em especial, mas pode ser que ele exija um cuidado maior em um caso no "mundo real" – por exemplo, quantidade de produtos, histórico de equipes para um vendedor etc.

Espero ter ajudado. :)

Comment: Rodrigo não teria como deixar a tabela equipe sendo informada na tabela Vendedor e Venda?

Comment: @JorgeToledo Se você vincular a equipe com o vendedor, dirá qual é a equipe atual do vendedor. Se você vincular a tabela equipe com venda, dirá qual foi a equipe do vendedor no ato da venda. Você ainda pode fazer ambos os vínculos ao mesmo tempo, se preferir, todas as abordagens são válidas.

Comment: Ok, Rodrigo, muito obrigado vou fazer aqui.

Answer (score 5):

Do jeito que está, na tabela `vendas` não dá para saber em qual equipe o vendedor estava quando a venda foi realizada, uma vez que ele pode mudar de equipe depois de fazer a venda. A solução mais simples para isso (existem outras) seria simplesmente acrescentar um campo `id_equipe` na tabela `vendas` que corresponde a equipe na qual o vendedor estava quando a venda foi efetuada.

Além disso, não há na tabela `vendas` nada que indique quando uma determinada venda foi realizada, assim não dá para saber quais foram vendidos nos primeiros 15 dias de Janeiro ou coisa parecida. A solução mais óbvia para isso seria acrescentar um campo `data_venda` na tabela `vendas` do tipo `timestamp`.

---

Consulta que trás os produtos vendidos por um determinado vendedor em um determinado período:

```
SELECT v.id, v.data_venda, vd.nome AS nome_vendedor, e.nome AS nome_equipe, v.produto
FROM vendas v
INNER JOIN vendedor vd ON v.id_vendedor = vd.id
INNER JOIN equipe e ON v.id_equipe = e.id
WHERE v.id_vendedor = :id_vendedor
AND v.data_venda BETWEEN :limite_inferior AND :limite_superior
```

Aonde `:id_vendedor` é o id do vendedor de quem deseja-se obter as vendas realizadas e `:limite_inferior` e `:limite_superior` é o período a ser considerado.

---

Consulta que mostra a quantia de produtos vendidos por equipe em um determinado período:

```
SELECT e.id, e.nome, COUNT(v.id) AS qtd, v.id_equipe
FROM vendas v
INNER JOIN equipe e ON v.id_equipe = e.id
WHERE v.data_venda BETWEEN :limite_inferior AND :limite_superior
GROUP BY v.id_equipe
```

Aonde `:limite_inferior` e `:limite_superior` é o período a ser considerado.

---

Consulta que mostra a quantia de produtos vendidos por equipe e por vendedor em um determinado período:

```
SELECT e.id AS id_equipe, e.nome AS nome_equipe, vd.id AS id_vendedor, vd.nome AS nome_vendedor, COUNT(v.id) AS qtd, v.id_equipe, v.id_vendedor
FROM vendas v
INNER JOIN vendedor vd ON v.id_vendedor = vd.id
INNER JOIN equipe e ON v.id_equipe = e.id
WHERE v.data_venda BETWEEN :limite_inferior AND :limite_superior
GROUP BY v.id_equipe, vd.id
```

Aonde `:limite_inferior` e `:limite_superior` é o período a ser considerado.